# Kalman-Filter Estimate the position

Tags: python, kalman-filters

I am quite new in this field and trying to learn Kalman-Filter but i am quite lost how to start my task.

This is the file description 
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28p0z.jpg). I guess the state vector x must be the poistion of light towers? so a 6D- Kalman-Filter? And after finding it, how do I proceed it?

Comment: Homework?  Aren't the positions of the light towers given as a part of the problem?  If they're known, why are you trying to determine them?  What *do* you want to know in the context of the problem?

Comment: I am trying to find the state vector x

Comment: I asked you "what is the shape of your forest?", and you said "the lichen on the tree bark is grey".  So let's try again -- what is the shape of your forest?  If you ignore the fact that it's a Kalman filter, ignore the fact that there's something called a "state variable", what do you **actually need to know** to keep the boat from running aground on a shoal?

Comment: What I know is,  that my state vector is x = (x1,x2) at this point, how to continue?

Comment: "So a 6D Kalman Filter?"  "What I know is, that my state vector is x = (x1,x2) at this point..."  Are these statements consistent?  Given your stated state vector, what **must** the dimensionality of your Kalman filter be?

Comment: And, separately, when was the last time you watched a movie and saw the first mate say "Cap'n!  x1 = 30 and x2 = 55, we're all gonna die!!!"  **Drop the math for the moment**.  What, **intuitively** do you need to know about the boat to avoid the shoals?  What is the **name** of the thing, in **English** (or your native language)?